# parsec error with ambigious types

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm writing a wiki parser using haskell and I have run into this wierd problem. My code right now looks like this

```
import System.Environment
import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>), many)

import Control.Monad
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy

data RichText = UText String
              | DText String
              deriving (Show)

parseBold = do
  string "\'\'\'"
  manyTill anyChar (try (string "\'\'\'"))

parseItalic = do
  string "\'\'"
  manyTill anyChar (try (string "\'\'"))

parsefunc content = do
  case (parse parseItalic "parsing" content) of
    Right result -> return result
    Left error -> return "some error!"

main = do
  content:_ <- getArgs
  result <- parsefunc content
  print result
```

If I comment out parseItalic and use parseBold, it works. If I comment out parseBold and use parseItalic, it works.
But both don't work at the same time... It throws an error

```
   No instance for (Stream s0 m0 Char) arising from a use of `string'
   The type variables `s0', `m0' are ambiguous
   Relevant bindings include
     parseBold :: ParsecT s0 u m0 [Char] (bound at wi.hs:13:1)
   Note: there are several potential instances:
     instance Monad m => Stream [tok] m tok
       -- Defined in `Text.Parsec.String'
     instance Monad m =>
              Stream Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString m Char
       -- Defined in `Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy'
     instance Monad m =>
              Stream Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString m Char
       -- Defined in `Text.Parsec.ByteString'
   In a stmt of a 'do' block: string "'''"
   In the expression:
     do { string "'''";
          manyTill anyChar (try (string "'''")) }
   In an equation for `parseBold':
       parseBold
         = do { string "'''";
                manyTill anyChar (try (string "'''")) }
```

I'm not able to understand what is this error. Obviously my type is a string (which is nothing but [Char]) but why is the compiler complaining that it is Char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported both

```
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy
```

The former parses "Stream Char" and the latter "Stream Word8". So you have to get rid of `ByteString.Lazy` to leave just one variant. If you need both (e.g. you intend to parse ByteString as well as String using polymorphic functions), you have to explicitly parametrise Stream.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ambiguity error.

The type of the parsers can be either `Text.Parsec.String.Parser` or `Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy.Parser`, and the compiler doesn't know which to choose.

You can get the code to compile if you add the types....

```
parseBold::Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy.Parser String
parseBold = do
....etc
```

There are other ways to fix the ambiguity....

You could use `parseBold`/`parseItalic` somewhere else where the types would be inferred, or you could clean up the imports so that only one case is allowed.